# Why aren't things massless when they have balanced forces acting on them?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

Since $0$ divided by anything is $0$, why isn't everything with a net force of $0$ massless? Since $F = ma$ rearranges to $m = F/a$, when $F = 0$, $m$ should equal $0$, shouldn't it? This obviously can't be true, because it doesn't make any sense; but why?

Comment: 0 divided by anything - ***except 0*** - is 0. Important exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have $F=0$ all you can say is that $m a=0$.

Now, in classical mechanics, the mass $m$ is a property of the object you are studying, and it is generally assumed that $m > 0$. Thus you can divide $ma=0$ on both sides by $m$ and obtain $a=0$, which gives you Newton's first law: an object with no net force applied to it, moves at constant velocity.

See that you cannot divide both sides of $ma=0$ by $a$ because $a=0$ and division by $0$ is not defined.

The reason we take $m>0$ in classical mechanics is as follows. Classical mechanics lets you calculate the movement of objects using your knowledge of the forces applied to it and the equation $F=ma$. You see that if you were to put $m=0$ in the equation, you need either $F=0$ (there can be no force whatsoever) or $a=\infty$ (things fly around at infinite velocity, whatever *that* means) or other combinations in which the theory would be **completely useless**.

So classical mechanics $F=ma$ is a useful theory only when considering objects which do have a mass. Now, there are objects with no mass (like the photons: the particles of light), but for those you need other theories.

Comment: So in classical mechanics, you **have** to assume that there **is** a mass?

Comment: Basically, yes.

Comment: I disagree with that. When you do problems in which the body is assumed to be ideally massless (pulleys, ropes, springs, etc.), the law is still **applicable** but **useless** as it cannot give any information about the acceleration of the body. In that case, some constraints can help to find the same.

Comment: @KarthikSharma While it's true that you can assume strings, pulleys and other objects to be massive, you will still need to have at least one finite mass to apply Newton's law of motion and get dynamics.

Answer (score 2):

You've uncovered an additional assumption of classical mechanics!

Classical mechanics is not just Newton's laws. The equation $F = ma$ contains two new, unknown quantities: the force $F$ and the mass $m$. (We already know how to measure acceleration.) As a result, the equation is totally useless unless we also know something about $F$ and something about $m$.

The information from $F$ comes from force laws, like Hooke's $F = -kx$ or gravity $F = mg$. However, even knowing what force is, the equation remains useless because it can always be satisfied if you allow mass $m$ to vary in a really weird way.

Newton knew this, which is why he addresses this in the very first sentence in Principia Mathematica! He gives a totally useless definition of mass, but one that makes it clear that the mass of an object doesn't change unless the object itself is changed. (He essentially says "Okay, we all already know what mass is. It's just the amount of stuff.") That's why you don't get $m = 0$ when $a = 0$. It's assumed to stay the same.

Comment: Chapeau! great answer

Comment: So, ultimately, $F=ma$ is just useless _unless_ there is a mass? It simply doesn't work if there isn't actually a massive object for a force to work upon?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other answers, but consider also the following.

Physical reality is modeled by mathematics, but mathematics is not physical reality. If one considers causality as a constraint to physical reality in the frame of classical physics, then there is a better way to express Newton's  2nd law by considering the logical order in which things occur
$$a=\frac{\Sigma F}{m}$$
since it's the net force that leads to movement, not the movement that leads to force.

Not that $\Sigma F=ma$ is *wrong* but rather incomplete, since cauaslity was not taken into account.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really understand what you're trying to say about causality. What do you mean and how does it affect the problem? Also, does sigma $ F$ just mean net $F$?

Comment: @ClaytonMcCray in any 'system' whether mathematical or physical, one needs to consider the completeness of the system's description. That means that all inputs and outputs are defined, all structures relating those inputs and outputs are defined, initial conditions are defined, etc.. In mathematics we do not necessarily have to deal with causality and in physics we may attribute the adjective 'static' to describe a structural relationship - like Newton's 2nd law. But in reality (real physical systems) things are dynamic - they depend on time. And with time there is cause and effect...

Comment: @ClaytonMcCray  ... either A happens before B or B happens before A. For Newton's 2nd law I believe we can safely say you need to first begin with a force before you can achieve movement. So the missing structure I'm referring to is the causality constraint. If you adhere strongly to that, you'll want to write the equation in the manner I've written it.

Comment: @docscience when you say, that force leads to movement and not movement leads to force... If you are working in non-inertial coordinates, then you will see bodies follow newtons equations with the addition of fictitious forces. In this case movement does lead to forces. Also, Gravity is a fictitious force.

Comment: @AndreaDiBiagio but are not those forces you refer to only written in the mathematical equations and not tied to causality constraints? Physically what's really happening?

Comment: I'm not sure about what you mean by "causality constraints".

Comment: @AndreaDiBiagio Newton's 2nd law in the form $F = ma$ doesn't imply in any manner whether the force comes first or the acceleration. Causality constraints tie down the order in which things occur: the cause and effect.

Comment: @docscience It seems to me that your "causality constraints" are a lens to which to understand the theory. To my understanding, acceleration and force are dual concepts: in some sense they are aspects of the same thing. You can think of your arm accelerating a ball, and in that case you would say force comes first; when you see an object fall, there is no way of measuring the force that accelerates it: you can only infer gravity from the acceleration. Beyond classical physics, in quantum field theory, particles and forces are understood to be the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

For F=ma when F=0, **mathematically** either m=0 or a=0 or both. But we know that m is not zero (unless stated that the body is massless), which gives a=0, where a is the acceleration of the center of mass of the system.

If you manipulate the equation as m = F/a, it doesn't make any difference as if we know that the body isn't massless, the acceleration (of COM) should be zero and your equation will yield 0/0 which is indeterminate form and is **not equal to zero**.

Comment: Furthermore the indeterminancy comes about from the linear relation of force to acceleration considering only a single point at (0,0) - from which an infinity of lines can intersect. For an experiment you need at least one other point to determine the mass.

Comment: @docscience I didn't get that. Can you please explain?

Comment: Mathematically speaking, Newtons 2nd law can be viewed as just a linear equation relating force to acceleration with a slope of *m*, mass. If we pick any point on the line other than the origin we can determine the mass since we assume the line goes through the origin (two points define a line). But if we pick the origin (zero force, zero acceleration) we have no second point of reference, so *any* line fits. The mass is indeterminate.